# How to increase the Jquery grid - serial number column width size

Tags: jquery, html, struts2, struts-html

I am using struts2-jquery grid to display my server values. I am using struts2-jquery-plugin-3.1.1.jar .

In my struts grid, I have a parameter named **rownumbers**.
as,

```
<sjg:grid rownumbers= true> 
</sjg:grid>
```

When I set the parameter rownumbers to true, I get the row numbers for each row in the grid table. How can I increase the width of my serial number td. I tried to update the css style. But it haven't worked.

Can anyone say me how to increase the width of the serail number column in struts-jquery grid?

Answer (score 0):

There is one option to control the width of the row numbers columns by settings the `rownumWidth` property (default is 25).

http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/appearance/rownumbers/default.php